# Spring with jsp

Tags: java, spring, maven

**Whitelabel Error Page**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Sep 26 12:30:38 IST 2020

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

**HomeController.java**

```
package com.JspPRo.Jspdemo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String homepage()
  {
    return "index.jsp";
  }

}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.JspPro</groupId>
<artifactId>JspProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>JspProject</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- 
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper 
-->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
<version>9.0.38</version>
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**index.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head> 
 <body>
 hi welcome java 
</body>
</html>
```

**I dont know why its happen. plese help me to solve this i cant run jsp page.i am using spring version 4.8.0.RELEASE**

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to your project setup, where have you placed the index.jsp file? Spring cannot find the file in the directory, so you have most likely placed it in the wrong folder.

Comment: src->main->webapp-WEB-INF->views->index.jsp